# How to interface with the NT mount manager to assign a driveletter?

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, wdk

I'm attempting to replace some legacy `DefineDosDevice` userspace code (which doesn't work on Vista with Administrator users due to the fact that the elevated and normal session are represented by different DosDevice stores, therefore creating the rather strange scenario that the drive is visible if created from unelevated processes, but invisible if created from an elevated process).

The replacement for this, as I've found out through examining the [Truecrypt source](http://www.truecrypt.org/) and this [WDM sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VirtualVolume-83334efd) is to issue `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_VOLUME_ARRIVAL_NOTIFICATION` messages to mountmgr.sys and then `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT` / `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_DELETE_POINT`.

So this is what I'm doing - my code looks like this:

Firstly, various locals:

```
NTSTATUS ntStatus;
PDEVICE_EXTENSION device_extension;
UNICODE_STRING uVolumeName;

ULONG mntNameLen = 0;
ULONG mntPointLen = 0;
PMOUNTMGR_TARGET_NAME mntName = NULL;
PMOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT_INPUT mntPoint =  NULL;
```

Then, I construct and make my two requests. The first fails with the above status code. The second fails with a different status code (but isn't expected to work if the first fails).

```
mntNameLen = sizeof(MOUNTMGR_TARGET_NAME) + device_extension->sDevName.Length;
mntName = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, mntNameLen);

mntName->DeviceNameLength = device_extension->sDevName.Length;
RtlCopyMemory(mntName->DeviceName, device_extension->sDevName.Buffer, 
              mntName->DeviceNameLength);

ntStatus = MakeDeviceIoRequest (MOUNTMGR_DEVICE_NAME, 
    IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_VOLUME_ARRIVAL_NOTIFICATION,
    mntName, mntNameLen, 0, 0);

mntPointLen = sizeof(PMOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT_INPUT) + 
    device_extension->sDevName.Length + uVolumeName.Length;
mntPoint = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, mntPointLen);

mntPoint->SymbolicLinkNameOffset = sizeof (MOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT_INPUT);
RtlCopyMemory(&mntPoint+mntPoint->SymbolicLinkNameOffset, 
    uVolumeName.Buffer, uVolumeName.Length * sizeof(WCHAR));
mntPoint->SymbolicLinkNameLength = uVolumeName.Length;

mntPoint->DeviceNameOffset = mntPoint->SymbolicLinkNameOffset + 
    mntPoint->SymbolicLinkNameLength;
RtlCopyMemory(&mntPoint+mntPoint->DeviceNameOffset, 
    device_extension->sDevName.Buffer, device_extension->sDevName.Length);
mntPoint->DeviceNameLength = device_extension->sDevName.Length;

ntStatus = MakeDeviceIoRequest(MOUNTMGR_DEVICE_NAME, 
    IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_CREATE_POINT, mntPoint,
mntPointLen, 0, 0);
```

Then I create the symbolic link \GLOBAL??\L: -> \Device\DeviceName

```
ntStatus = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&uVolumeName, &(device_extension->sDevName));
DbgPrint("Mapped %wZ -> %wZ\n", &uVolumeName, &(device_extension->sDevName));
RtlFreeUnicodeString(&uVolumeName);
if ( mntName != NULL )
{
    ExFreePool(mntName);
}
if ( mntPoint != NULL)
{
    ExFreePool(mntPoint);
}
```

However, the `ntStatus` response from the mount manager is `0xC0000010` `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`; my device string is of the form `\Device\DevName` and responds to each of:

- IOCTL_VOLUME_ONLINE
- IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_SUGGESTED_LINK_NAME
- IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_UNIQUE_ID
- IOCTL_MOUNTDEV_QUERY_DEVICE_NAME

and a list of other IOCTLs expected for a storage device. However, I have breakpoints set on all these routines and none of them are reached.

My Device is created via this little snippet:

```
// Security descriptor
RtlInitUnicodeString(&sddl,
     _T("D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;BU)(A;;GA;;;WD)"));

// named device
status = IoCreateDeviceSecure(
    DriverObject, 
    sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION),
    &device_name,     // \Device\DeviceName
    DeviceType,       // valid devicetype.
    0,
    FALSE,
    &sddl,            // security descriptor
    NULL,             // no idea what this does.
    &device_object    // output device object.
);
```

So, then, down to some questions:

1. Am I creating the messages for the mount manager correctly? The call MakeDeviceIoRequest basically wraps `IoCallDriver` and I'm reasonably confident that is not the problem.
2. Is anything I'm doing with `CreateDevice` a problem? I ask because I read [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2007/04/18/having-two-names-is-not-necessarily-better-than-one.aspx?Redirected=true) which implies something about device names, FDOs and PDOs that I honestly don't quite understand.
3. If I appear to be in way too deep, any chance of a clarification on my understanding of how this all works?

*Notes*: I have some restrictions. The code I am building on top of is fairly legacy, so I'm including `ntddk.h and wdmsec.h`; I can't change these to `wdm.h` or `ntifs.h` at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before diving into this any further, is there any chance you can move your calls to DefineDosDevice into a service? Calling it from a service puts the link in the Global directory, which will entirely get rid of the aliasing issue that you have.

If you can't do that, my first guess is that you're not handling some other required mount manager IOCTL. I know you have breakpoints on all of the specific IOCTLs, but do you have a breakpoint in your default handler? Usually that's where STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST comes from.

Comment: Hmmm, I forgot the default handler. Definitely worth looking at - will give it a try. On services - we actually do that already :( That was the original workaround, but we're trying to do away with the service code entirely. I'll get back to you on the default handlers, won't be until Monday though.

Comment: So I tried watching the default handler - turns out the mount manager sends [`IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_GPT_ATTRIBUTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regardless of whether the disk is described as GPT - or in this case, a virtual CD rom. Implementing that with an appropriate response makes the volume arrival notification return success. The remaining issue is create moint point, but having looked at the memory of the input I can see why it isn't working and it's due to my bad coding, so have a green tick :)